# Why this PHP code if else condition is not working?

Tags: php

CHECK THE IF ELSE STATEMENT ON after the `if (!empty) {}` section.

```
<form action="first.php" method ="post">
 <input type="text" name="username" >Username</br>
 <input type="password" name="password" >Password</br>
 <input type="submit"  value="Submit"></br>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['username'] )&& isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if (!empty($user) && !empty($pass)) {
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];

        if ($user ==="habib"  && $pass === "1234") {
            echo $user;
            echo $pass;
        } else {
            echo "wrong password and username";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This isn't php code.

Comment: It's just html, and there are no `if else` statement

Comment: Also this has nothing to do with `phpmyadmin`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check whether `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` are not empty, rather than `$user` and `$pass`.

Comment: <form action="first.php" method ="post">

  <input type="text" name="username" value="username" >Username</br>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="password">Password</br>
  <input type="submit"  value="Submit"></br>

</form>


<?php
  if(isset($_POST['username'] )&& isset($_POST['password'])){
  
  $user = $_POST['username'];
  $pass = $_POST['password'];
  
  if(!empty($user) && !empty($pass)){
  
   if($user ==="habib"  && $pass === "1234"){
    echo $user;
    echo $pass;
  
   }else{
    echo "wrong password and user name";
      }
  }else{

   echo "All fields required";
  }
 }
?>

Comment: Great, if the answer help, can you please upvote and accept it?